# How to access to specific item after for_each in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a list of variables (name of lambda function). I want to generate lambda function on aws lambda. Most of them have same configuration but 1 of them have different of memory size and environment variables. After I finish the block resource (with for_each calling that block) how can I call that reference to change configuration.

This is file main.tf in module lambda

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  function_name = <existed var>
  s3_bucket = <existed var>
  s3_key    = <existed var>
  runtime = <existed var>
  handler = <existed var>
  memory_size = 512
  timeout     = 30
  role = <existed var>
  environment {  
    variables = {
      ENV             = "${var.env}"    
      POOL_ID         = "${var.pooid}"
    }

  }
```

This is main.tf file in root level

```
module "aws_lambda_nodejs" {
  source = "../../Modules/Lambda"
  for_each               = var.lambda_nodejs_api_path_part
  env                    = var.env  
  function_name          = each.key
  s3_bucket              = module.aws_s3_bucket.lambda_bucket_id
  s3_key                 = "${each.key}.zip"
  runtime                = var.nodejs_runtime
  handler                = var.nodejs_handler
  role                   = module.bootstrap.lambda_role_arn
  aws_api_gateway_rest_api_id   = module.aws_api_gateway.aws_api_gateway_rest_api_id
  aws_api_gateway_method        = "*/"
  aws_api_gateway_resource_path = each.value
  aws_region                    = var.aws_region
  account_id                    = var.account_id
  pooid                         = var.pooid  
}
```

My target is:
var.lambda_nodejs_api_path_part = ["functionA", "functionB", "functionC",..etc]

function A

```
{
 memory_size = 1536, 
 environment = {
  ENV=dev, 
  poolId=eyjudb123, 
  configpath="/env/cfg"
 }
}
```

other function

```
{
 memory_size = 512, 
 environment = {
  ENV=dev, 
  poolId=eyjudb123,
 }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `lambda_nodejs_api_path_part` and what errors do you get?

Comment: Its my list of string contain lambda name I want to create. And for now, no errors. I just dont know how to edit a specific resource being managed inside of block

Comment: For example: lambda_nodejs_api_path_part = ["function_A", "function_B", function_C"]
I want to archive 
function A {memory_size = 1536, env = {env=dev, poolId=exnsahsd, configpath="/env/cfg"}}
other function
{memory_size = 512, env = {env=dev, poolId=exnsahsd}

Comment: Please update the question with properly formatted new code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I add a new formatted goal for function A in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After I finish the block resource (with for_each calling that block) how can I call that reference to change configuration.

This is not how Terraform works. In Terraform you define the desired state for each resource and that exactly once. Terraform then manages for you to get the resources in that state. There is no iterative approach like *"first do this for all resources and then do that for other resources"*.

What you might want to do to achieve your goal is

- Add memory size as an additional variable to your lambda module.
- Pass different values to that variable for different instances.

**root module main.tf**

```
module "aws_lambda_nodejs" {
  source = "../../Modules/Lambda"
  for_each               = var.lambda_nodejs_api_path_part
  env                    = var.env  
  function_name          = each.key
  memory_size            = each.key == "function A" ? 1536 : 512
  ...
}
```

**Modules/Lambda/main.tf**

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "pabx_function" {
  ...
  memory_size = var.memory_size
  ...
}
```

**Modules/Lambda/variables.tf**

```
variable "memory_size" {
  type = number
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if all 30 functions have same similar configuration, but they all have different in specific environment variable I have to put condition one by one right?

Comment: @Dragneol I'm not sure if I get this right. In case each of the functions requires a different memory size, I would use a custom object as variable type and define `lambda_nodejs_api_path_part` and `memory_size` as attributes to that object type. 
Then iterate over a list of these objects to create the module.